# Why does splitWithProportion change the amount in each set whenever it is called?

Tags: python, python-2.7, neural-network, pybrain

Using [Python](http://python.org/) 2.7.6 and [Pybrain](http://pybrain.org) 0.3...

Here is a function I've written to create a data set to train my neural network.

It is a [sequential data set](http://pybrain.org/docs/api/datasets/sequentialdataset.html) and I want 75% of it to be training data and 25% test data (I believe that's an accepted reasonable split):

```
from pybrain.datasets import SequentialDataSet

def create_data_sets(rows):

    ds = SequentialDataSet(13, 1)
    last_id = -1
    count = 0

    for row in rows:

        current_id = int(row[14])
        if current_id != last_id:
            count += 1
            ds.newSequence()
        last_id = current_id

        ds.appendLinked(
            [int(row[0]) / 10000.0, 
             int(row[1]) / 10000.0, 
             int(row[2]) / 20.0, 
             int(row[3]) / 9.0, 
             int(row[4]) / 9.0, 
             int(row[5]) / 6.0, 
             int(row[6]) / 6.0,
             float(row[7]), 
             float(row[8]), 
             float(row[9]), 
             float(row[10]), 
             int(row[11]) / 6.0,
             int(row[12]) / 6.0], 
             [float(row[13])])

    test_data, train_data = ds.splitWithProportion(0.25)        
    return (test_data, train_data, count)
```

Now I call that function twice, with the same data like so (covered up the query, as the table and column names are a bit sensitive, sorry):

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O from P order by O,A')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
connection.close()

test_data, train_data, count = create_data_sets(rows)   
print str(len(test_data)) + " " + str(len(train_data)) + " " + str(count)

test_data, train_data, count = create_data_sets(rows)   
print str(len(test_data)) + " " + str(len(train_data)) + " " + str(count)
```

Looking at the output I get this (actually, each time I run it, it changes):

```
400 1222 203
386 1236 203
```

That is confusing me - why is it splitting the data differently each time?

Since the data set order is not changing, I'd expect it to just do the same thing every time I call it.  Is there some magic happening inside here?

---

**Update**

Here's another, simpler, example:

```
from pybrain import datasets

d = datasets.SequentialDataSet(0, 1)
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.newSequence()
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.newSequence()
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.newSequence()
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])

for _ in range(2):
    test, train = d.splitWithProportion(0.25)
    print str(len(test)) + " " + str(len(train))
```

I sometimes get output

```
5 18
6 17
```

It seems that each time `splitWithProportion` is called it can round the sets differently, so I guess that it must be randomizing the sequences or something perhaps - as you can see I am not adjusting the data.  I'm confused as to why it would need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem has something to do with how you are creating new sequences

```
        if current_id != last_id:
        count += 1
        ds.newSequence()
```

I have verified that the following returns consistent results of "6 18" every time it's called.

```
from pybrain import datasets

d = datasets.SequentialDataSet(0, 1)
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.newSequence()
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.newSequence()
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.newSequence()
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
d.addSample([],[0])
d.addSample([],[1])
test, train = d.splitWithProportion(0.25)
print str(len(test)) + " " + str(len(train))
```

EDIT:
The thing to remember with a SequentialDataSet is that the split is along the sequences not the individual samples. So with 4 sequences a 0.25 split will give exactly 1 sequence for test and 3 sequences for training. If the sequences are not the same length then you would end up with different len() results for test and train. Everything is working as expected for the sequential dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Your sequences are all the same size (6 in each) though.  If you vary them a little bit you will also see the phenomenon.  I've added a version of your code as an example to my question so you can see

Comment: I clarified the answer, should make sense to you now.

Comment: Thanks - I understand that I would get 1 for test and 3 for training in a set with 4 sequences and that, of course, due to rounding if the set is not divisible by 4 I would expect to only have whole numbers of sequences in the two sets but the question I'm trying to ask, albeit badly I guess (sorry) is why is it not consistently the same sequences in the split data sets - notice I am simply calling splitWithProportion twice on exactly the same dataset and yet the size of the two resulting sets varies.  I think there must be some randomness there, but I don't understand why it would be needed.

Comment: Because it's spliting the sequences. So if you have 4 sequences, 3 of the sequences have 4 items and one sequence has 3 items. Your total number of items would be 15. Now when you split with proportions 0.25 you end up with 3 sequences for training and 1 sequence for testing. The random part comes into the sequences, IF the sequence chosen for testing is the sequence with 3 items you end up with 12 items for training and 3 for test. IF the sequence chosen for testing is one of the 4 item sequences you will have 11 items for training and 4 for testing. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Great, thanks, so you confirm my suspicion that it is random.  My question is, however, why is it randomly choosing which sequences to use for test and train?  Is that usual in machine learning?  I expected that if I want it to be random I would call randomize on the dataset but it is randomizing it for me just when I call the split function and that is what I am asking - why is it doing this for me? (I should learn to ask my questions clearer I guess!  Thanks for sticking with me)